# jquery code causes unwanted space

Tags: jquery, html, jsfiddle

I am having an issue with an options and answers feature I have. If I select an options which contains an output of some many buttons e.g If I choose option 20, it will display 20 buttons, the problem I am getting is that at the bottom of the table column, the space drops down a little bit. It only does it when an option is changed and then the space remains throughout. My question is simply how can I stop the space at the bottom of the table column to increase when an option changes?

I have found out that the code that is causing this problem is this:

```
  //THE ISSUE IS HERE

var _x = $(e.currentTarget);
var _y = _x.closest('td.extratd');
var _z = _y.prev();

$('textarea', _z).css('height', '').height(_z.innerHeight());

//ISSUE ABOVE
```

Now what the code above does is allow the textarea within the `Question` column to fill the whole table cell when ever the textarea is appended or if the option changes. So I need the code above but what the code above also does is create an unnecessary space at the bottom of the table row so I need help to sort out the unwanted space.

I have a jsfiddle here which you can use to see what is happening and it also includes the code above: http://jsfiddle.net/aND4g/61/

Please follow steps below in order to use fiddle:

1. When you open fiddle, on top type in a content in the question textarea and then click on `Open Grid` and select button `3` or `4`.
2. When you have done step 1 then click on the `Add Question` button to append the above details into the table below
3. Now WITHIN THE APPENDED ROW, click on the `Open Grid` and select the other option from what you first chosen. You will see that it creates an unwanted space at the bottom of the table row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using `innerHeight()`, which includes `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`.

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements, including padding but not border.
>
> -- [`innerHeight()` API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/)

Since these are both equal to `1em`, you're getting `2em` more height than you want. So, I implemented a quick-and-hacky fix:

```
// Get the padding of the cell
var ignoreHeight = parseInt(_z.css("padding-top")) + parseInt(_z.css("padding-bottom"));
// Set the height without that padding
$('textarea', _z).css('height', '').height(_z.innerHeight() - ignoreHeight);
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aND4g/66/)**

Basically, I just added the padding into a variable, and subtracted that from the actual height you're setting. There might be a better way you can "ignore" this padding with some nicer method, but it seems to me this will work for your case.

Comment: All im bothered about is that it is fixed and you have fixed it, thank you :)